# Handling c++ wxWidgets EVT_MAXIMIZE macro

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a (maybe) simple question. I'd like to resize my program window after the user clicked on "maximize" since I want to fit the data to the window, without leaving "grey patches" (hope it does make sense lol, since I'm from Italy I'm not sure it does) . The problem is if I try to show a simple message, it doesn't show up. This is the piece of code I think you need to look at of my class (cpp file)

```
void EBCFrame::OnMaximize(wxMaximizeEvent& event)
{
//    _window->Fit();
    wxMessageBox(_T("maximize test"));
}

// Event table for EBCFrame
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(EBCFrame, wxFrame)
    ...
    EVT_MAXIMIZE(EBCFrame::OnMaximize)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

And here's the header file

```
class EBCFrame : public wxFrame
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        EBCFrame(const wxString& title);
        // Event handlers
        .....
        void OnMaximize(wxMaximizeEvent& event);

    private:
        // This class handles events
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()

        wxScrolledWindow* _window;
        ....
};
```

I apologize if it's not enough and you need the full code; in that case, I'll provide as soon as I read this question again. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Is the maximize event even firing?  The docs say that it's only generated for the wxMSW, wxGTK, wxOSX/Cocoa and wxOS2 ports (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_maximize_event.html)  Do any events (like wxEVT_SIZE) work for you?

Comment: Thanks, the problem it doesn't fire at all. I tried to use a EVT_SIZE macro for a test, but if I just change the event trigger without any change to the OnMaximize code, the program crashes at the startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your earlier question's code: [wxWidgets: can't inherit from wxListCtrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997366/wxwidgets-cant-inherit-from-wxlistctrl);

You seem to be using a wxScrolledWindow for a wxListCtrl which is not needed (the wxListCtrl already manages the scrolling of its content)  If that is the case, remove the wxScolledWindow from your code.

If that wxListCtrl (EBCList) is the only client window in your frame (EBCFrame), wxWidgets will size it automatically.

If you have added more widgets to your frame in the meantime, you may want to look into the sizer classes to compose your layout (e.g wxBoxSizer).

Comment: It worked, and you're definitely my angel (since you're always answering me lol) but can I ask you why it didn't work with the previous version? (thanks for the hint about the wxScrolledWindow, I thought I needed it) Because I'd like to understand why, it could be useful one day.
Before I posted here, I had a look to wxBoxSizer but, as far as I understand, I believed it'd be useful just for dialogs. Am I wrong? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking... When your frame has a single child window (created with the frame as parent) the frame will automatically size it to fit its client area. If you have multiple child windows, the frame does not know how to align them the way you want, in which case you have to use a wx*Sizer or a wxSplitterWindow.

Comment: so, if I have a "nephew" window (in my case: EBCFrame->wxScrolledWindow->EBCList) the "auto" fit doesn't work, and I need to use wxSizers.. right? That was the direction I was investigating into, but I didn't realize how to fit the list with wxSize... now I think I got it... thank you!

Comment: Here's a little tutorial for the wxBoxSizer [link](http://neume.sourceforge.net/sizerdemo/) and here's one showing different types of sizers [link](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/wxwidgetstutorial/layoutmanagement/). The latter also demonstrates how to nest sizers in complex layouts.